# How do I solve the Eloquent Javascript "Chess Board"?

Tags: javascript, eloquent

new coder here trying to learn JS. I did codecademy already and am working through Eloquent Javascript now. I finally got something together after scratching my head for a very long while... but it doesn't work! I'm not quite sure if I'm approaching this from the right angle but I do know I want to use the loops to track progress through the printing of the # based grid.

> Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid,
>   using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the
>   grid there is either a space or a “#” character. The characters should
>   form a chess board.
>   Passing this string to console.log should show something like this:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

***My code is below:***

```
    var chessBoard = "";
    var size = 8;

    for (var lineCounter = 1; lineCounter < size; lineCounter++) { 

        if (lineCounter%2 === 0) { /

/if lineCounter is an even number
        for (var charCounter = 1; charCounter < size; charCounter++) {
            var evenOdd = (charCounter%2 === 0);
            switch (evenOdd) {
                case true:
                    (chessBoard += "#");
                    break;
                case false:
                    (chessBoard += " ");
                    break;
                }
            }                   
        }
    else { //if lineCounter is an odd number
        for (var charCounter = 1; charCounter < size; charCounter++) {
            var evenOdd = (charCounter%2 === 0);
            switch (evenOdd) {
                case true:
                    (chessBoard += " ");
                    break;
                case false:
                    (chessBoard += "#");
                    break;
            }
            }                       
        }   
    chessBoard += "\n";
    }
    console.log(chessBoard);
```

The current output of the program is this:

```
# # # #
 # # # 
# # # #
 # # # 
# # # #
 # # # 
# # # #
```

Through some iterations, I've already learned a lot, but right now I already see an error - I'm clearly down to a 7x7 grid instead of the 8x8 I wanted to get. I suspect it has to do with me using "<" in my for loops, but not sure if there's a better way to tackle this instead of just adding an extra digit.

Comment: And what output does your code generate? How is that different from what you expect? (Please include your output in the question.)

Comment: The newline is `\n`, not `/n`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy you need to make two loops,
one for each row and the other for choosing the element you want to console.log (either ' ' or '#').

check the comments through solution

```
var size = 8; //this is the variable setting

var board = "";//this is the empty string we're going to add either ' ' , '#' or newline

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {   /*in the outer loop we add newline to seperate rows*/
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {/*every inner loop rappresents a line, and alternatively it's adding either ' ' or '#' to the string that's being populated*/
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Comment: I see that my mistake was originally including the console.log in the last outer for loop. This simplifies things dramatically.

Comment: you create a string and log it once... If you keep it simple it's easier to understand

Comment: why (x + y) tho? How to understand this part?

Comment: The (x+y) % 2 in the above answer is to check if the addition for x and y is odd or even and prints empty space " " (i.e) white or "#" (i.e) Black

Answer (score 8):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw706aut/)***

[I am a fan of chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/342/travis-j?tab=profile) :) In chess, there is the rule "White on right" which means that the first square of our chess board will be " ". Following that it will alternate every time there is an odd match between row and column.

```
var board = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
 for(var a = 0; a < 8; a++){
  board += (a % 2) == (i % 2) ? " " : "#";
 }
 board += "\n";
}
```

Viewing the board, it now shows an 8x8 grid

```
console.log(board);

 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Feel free to substitute `i` for a row number or `a` for a column number. Or set both to a size :) It will still work. For example, `a < 20` will give 20 columns

```
 # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # 
 # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # 
 # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # 
 # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: I like the rule 'white on right', but it might be good to add that this rule is to be interpreted from the viewer standpoint (e.g. you are looking down onto the board). The bottom row is your row (where your major and minor pieces go) and the rightmost cell of the bottom row must be white because 'white on right'. I also use the rule 'queen must match colors' to determine where the king and queen go for each player.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different approach.

Each row has four instances of either `_#` or `#_` (where the underscore is a space).

Even-numbered rows begin with `_#` and odd-numbered rows begin with `#_`:

```js
var chessBoard= '',
    size= 8,
    c;

for(var i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
  c= i%2 ? '# ' : ' #';
  for(var j = 0 ; j < size/2 ; j++) {
    chessBoard+= c;
  }
  chessBoard+= '\n';
}

console.log(chessBoard);
```

Comment: Rick, thanks for your code! I actually really like that idea of simplifying by merging the space with #. However, I need to be able to reuse the program by changing the "size" variable.

Comment: My original code omitted `size` but I've now added it.  Does it work better?

Comment: Rick, that one did the trick! Excuse my ignorance but in line 3, did you simply declare an empty variable `c` ? I'm really new to all this but already noticed that you whipped up the ternary operator to simply the if/else. Love that! 

Edit: Also, I gather that using modulo here: `i%2` results in a true/false value which then selects from the left or right of the colon. I was under the impression that the modulo operator returns the remainder...

Comment: Yes, I declared the variable `c` for use within the loop.  And good catch with the ternary operator (also known as the conditional operator).

Comment: Rick, thanks so much - learned a lot. Made a last minute edit to my last comment, regarding the modulo resulting in a remainder.

Comment: The modulo in `i%2` *does* return the remainder after division by 2 (either 1 or 0), which JavaScript interprets as `true` or `false`.  (All non-zero numbers are treated as `true` in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version

```
console.log((new Array(65).join().split("")).map( function(v,i) {
    return ( (i/8 >> 0 ) % 2 ? ( i%2 ? " " : "#") : (i%2 ? "#" : " ") ) +
           ( (i+1) %8 ? "" : "\n" );
}).join(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var chessBoard = "";
var size = 8;

for (var lineCounter = 1; lineCounter < size; lineCounter++) { 

    if (lineCounter%2 === 0) { //if lineCounter is an even number
        for (var charCounter = 1; charCounter < size; charCounter++) {
            var evenOdd = (charCounter%2 === 0);
            switch (evenOdd) {
                case true:
                    chessBoard += "#";
                    break;
                case false:
                    chessBoard += " ";
                    break;
                }
            }                   
        }
    else { //if lineCounter is an odd number
        for (var charCounter = 1; charCounter < size; charCounter++) {
            var evenOdd = (charCounter%2 === 0);
            switch (evenOdd) {
                case true:
                    chessBoard += " ";
                    break;
                case false:
                    chessBoard += "#";
                    break;
            }
        }                       
    }   
    chessBoard += "\n";
}
console.log(chessBoard);
```

Comment: This starts the first row with a `#` character instead of a space and so doesn't quite match the OP's requested output.

Answer (score 1):

Using only the knowledge provided up to that point in the book *Eloquent JavaScript* here is my solution:

```
   var board = "";
   var size = 8;

   // Outer for loop creates a new line** after each cycle of the inner for loop
   for (var lineCount = 0; lineCount < size; lineCount++) {
       //The nested for loop adds a character to the board variable on a single line proportional to the size variable
       for (var spaceCount = 0; spaceCount < size; spaceCount++) {
           //This if statement creates the offset lines in the example image by alternating the first character depending on the lineCount
           if (lineCount % 2 == 0) {
               var black = "#",
                   white = " ";
           } else {
               black = " ";
               white = "#";
           }
           if (spaceCount % 2 == 0) {
               board += white;
           } else {
               board += black;
           }
       }
       board += "\n"; //** new line created
   }
   console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my version.
Is not as clean and eloquent as the book one but it works!
    var size = 8;
    var board = " ";

```
for (var z = 0; z < size; z++) { 
 for (var y = 1; y < size; y++) { 
  if (board[y-1]===" ")
    board += "#";
  else 
    board += " ";
 } 
board += "\n";
console.log(board);
  if (board[0]===" ")
    board = "#";
  else 
    board = " ";      
 }
```

Comment: var size = 8;
var board = " ";

Comment: I don't believe this answer adds anything or improves on any of the other answers already posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = 8;
var block = '#';
var space = ' ';

for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  var line = '';

  for (var y = 1; y <= size; y++){
    if (i%2) {
        if (y%2) {
            line = line + space;
        } else {
            line = line + block;
        }
    } else {
        if (y%2) {
            line = line + block;
        } else {
            line = line + space;
        }
    }
  }

  console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution:

```
var size=8, line="", c="";
for (i=0;i<size;i+=1){
    i%2==0?c=" ":c="#"; 
    for(n=0;n<size;n+=1){
        c==" "?c="#":c=" ";     
        line+=c;    
    }   
    console.log(line);
    line=""
}
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to add some details explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to add mine :)

```
var times = 8; //set the times you want to run the loop
var result = '';//result is the chessboard.
for(var i = 0; i < times; i++){ //run the loop starting at zero and going up.
  for(var x = 0; x <= 4; x++){ //run a second loop to run each line of the chessboard.
    if(i % 2 === 0){ //check if i(current index of the loop) is divisible by 0, and concatenate '# ' to result
      result += '# ';
    }else{ //if not divisible by 0 then concatenate ' #'
      result += ' #';
    }
  }
  result = result + '\n' //add a line brake to at the end of every index 
}
console.log(result); //result should now print the chessboard.
```

Answer (score 0):

So me and some coding buddies were going back and forth optimizing this function for fun and education.

I didn't see our winning solution up here so why not throw it up?

```
function board(size) {
        // determine if we're dealing with an odd board size
    var odd=size%2,  
        // get size-1 if odd, so we can simplify things
        s=odd?size-1:size, 
        // our first row base
        r1 = " #",
        // our first row
        row1 = r1,
        // our second row base
        r2 = "# ",
        // our second row
        row2 = r2,
        // total size of board, including newlines
        total = (size*size)+size,
        // our output 
        out = "",
        // our board base
        o;

    // if size was 1, then it would be odd and s = 0
    // in that case return first row, first character
    // just a single white space
    if(!s) {
        return r1[0];
    }

    // next we build our rows with 2 loops
    // this first loop doubles each row until we're within 2*n of total length
    // we'd want to skip this step for small values of size
    for(n=2;2*n<s;n*=2) {
        row1+=row1;
        row2+=row2;
    }

    // this second loop adds our bases until we have the size length
    while(row1.length<s) {
        row1+=r1;
        row2+=r2;
    }

    // if our size is odd, then a row ends with the same character it begins with
    if(odd) {
        row1+=r1[0];
        row2+=r2[0];
    }

    // add our newlines to complete our rows
    row1+="\n";
    row2+="\n";

    // we do the same thing to build the board, 2 loops
    // start with our base of the 2 rows we just built
    out = o = row1+row2;

    // double up the rows until we're within 2*n rows of a full board
    // again, we'd want to skip this step for small values of size
    for(n=2;2*n<s;n*=2) {
        out+=out;
    }

    // add the base until we're complete or 1 row off (if odd)
    while(out.length+size+1<total) {
        out+=o;
    }

    // if odd add the first row as final row
    if(odd) {
        out+=row1;
    }

    // return the completed chessboard string
    return out;
}

// function call with size, returns our chessboard string
console.log(board(8));
```

If you remove the `for(n=2;2*n<s;n*=2)` loops then it'll run faster for generating smaller boards but keeping them in makes it much more efficient for larger boards.  Ideally you could calculate and specify a `threshold` and skip the `for` loops when `size<threshold`.

Answer (score 0):

this might be late but there are answers on the from the page itself see: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/

manipulate for loop/formulas for understanding like

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 1; x++) {

    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += (x+y)+"%";
    else
      board += (x+y)+"#";

  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried mine with while loops and a basic understanding of the books solution.

```
var board = ""
var size = 8
var x = 0
var y = 0

while (x < size) //restricts number of rows "size" times
  {
    while (y < size) //changes value of board to board+= # or " " a combined "size" times restricting columns to "size"
     {
         if ((x+y) % 2 == 0) //adding x+y ensures each row begins with altering #/_
            board += " "; //increases value of board by _
         else
            board += "#"; //increases value of board by _
         y++; // increases from 0-8 allowing loop to execute 8 times.
     }
    board += "\n";
    x++; // increases from 0-8 allowing loop to execute 8 times.
    y = 0; //resets vaule of y to 0 to allow inner loop to repeate
  }

console.log(board) // board prints as a repeating string of #_ using line breaks to create new rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sizeX = 8,
    sizeY = 8;
var emty = " #",
    grid = "# ";

for (x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
    if (x % 2) {
        console.log(emty.repeat(sizeY))
    } else {
        console.log(grid.repeat(sizeY))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes an alternative answer using ternary operator (my first contribution :D):

```
var size = 8; //this is the variable setting

var board = "";//this is the empty string we're going to add either ' ' , '#' or newline

for (var i = 0; i  < size; i++) {   /*in the outer loop we add newline to separate rows*/
  for (var j = 0; j  < size; j++) {/*every inner loop represents a column, and alternatively it's adding either ' ' or '#' to the string that's being populated*/
        ((i+j%2==0 ? board+=" ": board+="#") /*Here you can see the ternary operator. The syntax = condition ? true: false */
  }
board+="\n";
}; 
 console.log(board);
```

Comment: You probably mean `board+=((j+i)%2==0 ? " ": "#")`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following... It's not very eloquent but it worked for the scenerio.

```
var hash = ' # #';
var rehash = '# # ';
for( var i = 1; i<9; i++){
  if( i%2 ==0){
    console.log(rehash+ rehash);}
  else{
    console.log(hash + hash);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two independent FOR loops and it worked. Hopefully independent FOR loops makes it readable. Size of the board can be modified and it reflects accordingly.

```
size = 8
oddline  = ""
evenline = ""

/*First for loop is for creating the first and second lines*/
for (i=0;i<size/2;i++)
{
    oddline = oddline + "#" + " "
    evenline = evenline + " " + "#"
}

/* This for loop is for printing the first and second lines repeatedly */
for (j=0;j<size/2;j++)
{
console.log(oddline)
console.log(evenline)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution I'm sure but it works.

```
let chessBoard = "";
const boardSize = 8;

for (let yAxis = 0; yAxis < boardSize; yAxis++) {
  for (let xAxis = 0; xAxis < (boardSize / 2); xAxis++) {
    if (yAxis % 2 === 0) {
      chessBoard += " ";
      chessBoard += "#";
    }
    else {
      chessBoard += "#";
      chessBoard += " ";
    }
  }
  chessBoard += "\n";
}
console.log(chessBoard)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution using the [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method that I think is much cleaner than many of the solutions here:

```
var size = 8;
var grid = "";

for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
  if (i%2 == 0)
    grid += "# ".repeat(size/2) + "\n";
  else
    grid += " #".repeat(size/2) + "\n";
}

console.log(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function PrintChessBoard(x,y){
var newHashString = CreateHashString(8);
var charArray = newHashString.split('');
//var tempArry =[];
for(var i = 1 ; i<=y ;i++)
{
if(i % 2 ==0){
  for(var j=0 ; j<x; j=j+2){
    charArray[j+1] = ' ';

  }
}
else{
    for(var k=0 ; k<x ; k += 2){
    charArray[k] = ' ';

  }
 }
var HashString = ConcatArrayToString(charArray)
//reset array
charArray = newHashString.split('');
console.log(HashString);
}

}

function CreateHashString(x){
    var hashString = '';
    while(x>0){
      hashString +='X';
      x--;
    }
   return hashString;
}

function ConcatArrayToString(arr){
  var nS ='';
 for(var i = 0 ; i<arr.length ;i++){
   nS +=arr[i];
 }
 return nS;
}

PrintChessBoard(8,8);
```

Comment: Please edit you post and add explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wonders, there is a way to do this with only one loop:

```
var chess="";
var size=8;
var k=0, l=1;

//k is to check even for now
//l is for odd for now

var tmp;
var isEven=false;

//we check if chess is Even (if not isEven stays false)

if(size%2==0)
  isEven=true;

//sqSize tells us how many chess squares are there

sqSize= size*size;

for(var i=1; i<sqSize+1;i++){
  /*
  At the beginning of loop we check if the i is even
  When we have even ches e.g. 8x8 we need to swap condition
  every line (is i even? ----> is i odd? ---->etc.)
  */
  if (i%2==k)
    chess+=" ";
  else
    chess+="#";
  if (i%size==0){
    chess+="\n";
    //Adding new line every "size" number.
    /* 
    Here the the swap happens
    Earlier, we checked if the size is odd or even.
    Now we use this knowledge.
    k is condition value. we swap 0 to 1, so we will
    be checking different condition in the next loop passing.
    */
    if(isEven==true){
      tmp=k;
      k=l;
      l=tmp;
    }
  }

}
console.log(chess);
```

Comment: You'd still have the same number of iterations. you iterate over `size`*`size` once, but other solutions iterate twice on `size`, if your size is 8, you'd still have 64 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The official solution uses the newline character `/n` which I understand. By nesting the two `for` loops inside of each other, you can build up the whole chess board in one line. Sure.

But if I want to build an `oddRow` (starting with `#` and repeating across the width) and an `evenRow` (starting with `_` and repeating across the width) separately, then  print each row sequentially with a new `console.log` function here's how I did it.

The reason I'm taking this approach was because printing multiple `console.log` lines was just used in exercise 2.1 "looping a triangle" of the same book. It appears more logical to me, and this works.

```
  var size = 8;

  var evenRow = "";
  var oddRow = "";

  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    evenRow += " #";
    oddRow += "# ";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) //even
       console.log(evenRow); 
    else                  //odd
      console.log(oddRow);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simplified version of this:

```
function chessBoard(symbol, gridSize) {
    gridSize = gridSize || 8;
    symbol=symbol || "#";
    let pattern = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < gridSize/2; i++)
        pattern += symbol + " ";//Forming the pattern

    for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {

        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            console.log(pattern);
        }
        else {
            console.log(" " + pattern) //For even rows adding the space in front
        }
    }
}
chessBoard('#',8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = prompt("choose area of board"); // gets input to determine board size.
rowString = "";
for (let height = 0; height < num; height++){ // sets board height
  for(let width = 0; width < num; width++){ // sets board width
    if ((height+width) % 2 == 0){ // alternates chars by row & height position
      rowString += "# ";
    }
    else{
      rowString += "  ";
    }
  }
  rowString += "\n"; // after 'num' chars added to row, add new line to board
}
console.log(rowString);
```

The (height+row) % 2 == 0 on line 5 is important, as it determines whether it adds a " " or # to the rowString based on the height and row value. If it was just based on height you'd get alternating **columns** of #'s and " ", or if it was just based on width you'd get alternating **rows** of " " and #. If you consider the first point; height 0 width 0, it would evaluate even, height 1 width 1, odd etc.. next row height 1 width 0, odd etc... This ensures that your board is scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own code

```
let size = 8;
let fill = '#' 
let startWithSpace = true;
let addSpace  =  true ;
let board = '' ;
for(let i = 1; i <= size ; i++) 
  {


    let row = '' ;
    for(let column = 1; column <= size ; column++) 
      {

    if(addSpace) 
          {
            row += ' ' ;
            addSpace = false ;
           } 
        else
          {
            row += fill;
            addSpace = true;
           } 

       } 

    if(startWithSpace == true )
        {
          addSpace = false;
          startWithSpace = false;
        } 
    else
      {
        addSpace = true;
          startWithSpace = true;
       } 

    board+=row + "\n" ;
} 
console.log(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
let size = 16 ;
let fill = '#' ;
let space = " " ;
let board = '' 

for(i = 1; i <= size ; i++)
  {

    for(c = 1; c <=size ; c++)
    {
       board += (i + c) % 2 == 0 ? space : fill ;
    } 
    board += "\n" ;

  }

console.log(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach. I've added a detailed description in the JSDoc.

```js
/**
 * Eloquent JavaScript - Chapter 2 - Program Structure (Chessboard)
 * 
 * x = 8
 *
 *       # # # #
 *      # # # #
 *       # # # #
 *      # # # # 
 *       # # # #
 *      # # # # 
 *       # # # # 
 *      # # # # 
 *
 * Approach used:
 * 
 *  - If size of grid passed is 8, we'll have an 8x8 grid
 *  - Initialize an empty string
 *  - Loop through the grid size
 *      - If even iterator, start the row with a space, loop through (grid size - 1) and keep appending a '#'
 *      - If odd iterator, start the row with a '#', loop through (grid size - 1) and keep appending a space
 *      - After the inner loop finishes, we need to start a new line, so append '\n'
 *  - Once the loop has finished, we just return the result and that should be our required pattern
 *   
 *  
 * @param x Size of grid being displayed
 *
 */
function chessboard(sizeOfGrid) {
    var result          = ''
    var charHash        = '#'
    var charSpace       = ' '
    var charNewLine     = '\n'
    var remainderSize   = sizeOfGrid - 1
    var i, j
    for(i = 0; i < sizeOfGrid; i++) {
        if(i%2 === 0) {
            result += charSpace
            for(j = 0; j < remainderSize; j++) {
                if(j % 2 === 0) {
                    result += charHash
                } else {
                    result += charSpace
                }
            }
        } else {
            result += charHash
            for(j = 0; j < remainderSize; j++) {
                if(j % 2 === 0) {
                    result += charSpace
                } else {
                    result += charHash
                }
            }
        }
        result += charNewLine
    }
    return result
}

var result = chessboard(8)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using a Sting method called repeat()

Program goes as follows,

```
const pattern1 = ' #';
const pattern2 = '# ';
const binding = 4;

for(let i=1; i<9; i++){
  if(i % 2 !== 0){
    console.log(pattern1.repeat(binding));
  }else{
    console.log(pattern2.repeat(binding));
  }
};
```

The output would be,

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```js
const size = 8;
let board = "";

for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    board += `${(i % 2 === 0 ? " #" : "# ").repeat(size/2)}\n`;
}

console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
    let before = '# '
    let after = ' #'
    let size = 8
    for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        let pattern = ''
        for(let x = 1; x <= size/2; x++){
            if(i%2===0){pattern+= before}
            else{pattern+= after}  
        }
        console.log(pattern)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively...

```js
var holder = '';
var len = 4;

for (var count=0; count<len;count++)
    holder += '# '
    holder += '\n ' + holder;
    if (holder.length > len)
        for (var curr=0; curr<len; curr++)
            console.log(holder);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hehe, I think I made the most useless but working solution for this one

```
var string1 = " # # # #";
var string2 = "# # # # ";
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  if (i % 2 === 0){
      console.log(string1);
  }
  else{
      console.log(string2);
  }
}
```